# How to paste one image onto every images of a specific folder in python?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a image img2 which I want to paste on every image of a folder and save the new images in a new folder. Below is the code for one image. How can I loop over a specific folder and save new images in a new folder?

```
from PIL import Image
img1 = Image.open("2.png")
img1.show()
img2 = Image.open("1.png")
img1.paste(img2,mask=img2)
img1.save('3.png', quality=95)
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Here's the solution:

```
from PIL import Image
import glob

img_to_paste = 'logo.png'

img2 = Image.open(img_to_paste) #Image to paste into other images

count = 1 # Labels the new generated images

images = [] # List of opened images

# Opens all the images except the one to be pasted
for img in glob.glob('*.png'):
    if img != img_to_paste:
        images.append(Image.open(img))

for imag in images:
    imag.paste(img2)
    imag.save(f'folder/{count}.png')
    count += 1
```

Comment: I'm just glad I can help.

Answer (score 0):

Lets break your problem down into a few steps:

1. Convert your code into a function of an image file name
2. Find paths to all files in a specific folder
3. Execute your function on all image file paths

To do number one, do something like:

```
img2 = Image.open("1.png")

def function(img_path):
    img1 = Image.open(img_path).paste(img2,mask=img2)
    img1.save(img_path + 'modified')
```

For number two, use code modified from this:

```
import os
print([fn for fn in os.listdir(u'.') if os.path.isfile(fn)])
>>> ['main.py'] # list of files in same directory as python script
```

Maybe also parse the file paths to check whether they are valid file types or manually remove the python script.

```
pillow_filetypes = ['.jpg', '.jpeg', '.jpe', '.dib', '.jp2', '.bmp', '.png']
```

Let me know if that helped and ask me if you have any questions :)